# Mouseover product gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create product list page and mouseover gallery like [this page][1]

I tried with vertical carousel like that [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/genxer34/6svy9ocy/)

But it is not working like Zalando and jcarousel is not working 1.9.1+ jQuery version. I need a structure that works like Zalando.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.

Comment: Ok @Tushar I'm editing

Comment: Do you want to show the other options when hovering the main image?

Comment: @CliffBurton thnx for comment. Yes it is. When hovering main image show other image and click to up,down arrow show other thumb so hovering thumb changing main image like zalando.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are! I've encapsulated your entire product (lets call it `.product-item`) in a `<div>` so when hovering the main image (**or the other options when visible**) you can toggle the visibility of the options:

Make the options hidden by default (CSS):

```
#name-carousel {
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
```

Encapsulate your product in a container (HTML):

```
<div class="product-item"> <!-- This is the container -->
  <div id="name-carousel" class="container">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
      <li id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide1" /></li>
      <li id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide2" /></li>
      <li id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide3" /></li>
      <li id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide4" /></li>
      <li id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50&text=slide5" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="bigProductimage">
    <img data-img="http://placehold.it/400x200&text=slide0" src="http://placehold.it/400x200&text=slide0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Toggle the options visibility when hovering (jQuery):

```
productItem.hover(function() {
    $("#name-carousel").fadeToggle();
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/6svy9ocy/3/

Comment: Great! @CliffBurton thank you!. Can we use different jquery plugin? cause jquery.jcarousel.min.js not working on my page cause my page use 1.9.x + jquery version but jqcarosel is using 1.8.3 not supported higher version. :/ we can use different carousel. My general problem is that too.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, jCarousel is working fine here (http://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/6svy9ocy/4/) **notice that in the fiddle I changed the jQuery version to 1.9.1** - Can you show me why jCarousel is not working on jQuery 1.9.x? Do you have some error in console?

Comment: I did create a html file. with 1.9.1 not working . It should be work jquery-1.11.3. Cause im using bootstrap 3.3.5 version. Can you check this file http://we.tl/jQtJh7dwgG Yes i show some error you will see it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is too much work to do just to see an error for me, can you post here what the error states?

Comment: Ok. did you check my files?  Show this error on console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined and thumbnail up, down arrows not working.

Comment: Man you posted only `test_jcarousel.html`, I don't know if the file `jcarousel.js` is edited by you or is the original one but this seems to be another question, I think you have to ask a new one like _"jCarousel is not working properly in safari with jQuery 1.9.x but working in Chrome"_ attaching the fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/6svy9ocy/3/) where you and anyother possible answerer can see that everything works with jQuery 1.9.x in Chrome

Comment: jcarousel.js is copied from fiddle.I just add file on my local not edited anything. I should use  jQuery 1.11.3 version . My boostrap page is using it and if change or downgrade version not working bootstrap default carousel slider. Meanwhile i shoud use work with  jQuery 1.11.3 version thumbnail slider.